# How to Use ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock from Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to use

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(ctrlName, Page.GetType(), "msg", _script, false)
```

from Javascript function in

```
OnClientClick="CheckMaxLength(this);"
```

of TextBox. I want to show my custome PopUp.I am able to use it in .cs but I want it to use inside JavaScript.

Comment: Can you elaborate plz? You want to call a JS function to open a popup from inside of another function that is called in `OnClientClick`?

Comment: My Question is I have a TextBox I want to show my custom message Box once it is exceeding 5000 length in javascript may be textchange

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of that function is to make the client run a line of Javascript, *from the server*.

From Javascript code, you can simply run more code directly.

Comment: My Question is I have a TextBox I want to show my custom message Box once it is exceeding 5000 length in javascript may be textchange

Comment: @Fayaz: Yes; you need to write ordinary Javascript.  What did you try? What are you having trouble with?